I am trying to use jQuery 4 in webpack but I keep getting errors
I am trying to make a node js project the uses jQuery but my webpack config keeps sending errors.
I tried to research but even if the syntax looks right I still get errors.
The errors are all based on the basis of invalid syntax in the webpack config file.

And how should we help without knowing what those error messages are and how the config file looks like?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
